# Calculate skewness and Kurtosis of a grayscale image

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy

Is it possible to calculate the skewness and kurtosis of a grayscale image just using the functions

```
scipy.stats.kurtosis 
scipy.stats.skew
```

When I applied it showed an array and not a single value. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For grayscale image use this code:

```
from skimage import color
from skimage import io

im = color.rgb2gray(io.imread('Grayscale_image.png'))

from scipy.stats import skew, kurtosis

skew(im.reshape(-1))
kurtosis(im.reshape(-1))
```

Comment: Thanks, but could you explain me how this reshape works? How it makes everything converge to one single value, does it change the data?

Comment: In this case it reshape the array from matrix to vector. n×m matrix become nm×1 vector

Answer (score 0):

if I understood you, this code is for calculate skewness and kurtosis for one of the colors:

```
import scipy
import cv2

im = cv2.imread("image.jpg")

from scipy.stats import skew, kurtosis

colon_number = 0

print(skew(im.reshape(-1,3)[:,colon_number]))
print(kurtosis(im.reshape(-1,3)[:,colon_number]))
```

Comment: My question is, how do I obtain the kurtosis and skewness from a grayscale image? Because when I do that I get an array full of numbers

Comment: @asdas I add answer for grayscale image